# Topology of complex variety $Y^2=F(X)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Suppose $F\in\mathbb C[X]$ is a polynomial of degree $n=2k$ where $k\ge2$ is an integer. Suppose further that the $n$ roots $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are distinct. Then, consider the algebraic subset $S=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb C^2\;|\;w^2=P(z)\}$ of the plane $\mathbb C^2$. Is there a simple topological description of this set $S$ (such as a sphere with handles attached and some points removed)? Also, what is the topological description of the closure of $S$ in $\mathbb C\mathbb P^2$ (where we embed $\mathbb C^2$ in $\mathbb C\mathbb P^2$ as $(z,w)\mapsto[z:w:1]$)?
My guess is that $S$ is a genus $k-1$ surface with two points removed and that $\bar S$ (the closure) is a genus $k$ surface with one of the homology generators shrunk to a point). Are these descriptions correct?

Comment: Have you looked at one of the many books on "plane algebraic curves"?

Comment: Could you please suggest a book which deals with such questions?

Comment: I think Brieskorn's "Plane Algebraic Curves" does (though the treatment might be out of date), but maybe Milnor's "Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces" is a good place to start. I have mainly thought about the hypersurfaces of $\Bbb C^3$ (not of $\Bbb C^2$ as you are which of course should be easier...). I'm not sure I know a great modern source. I think there are probably people here who know much more about this than me.